# How do i make a timer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I would like to know if anyone knows how to make a stopwatch timer in flutter, so that when you press anywhere on the timer area the time starts and then do the same thing to start it. I want to have milliseconds and seconds visible, but then when the seconds reach 60 the minutes show and the seconds start back at 0,1,2... fill free to look at "twisty timer" in the play store to see  what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [Stopwatch class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) for the functionality. For the reference, you can look at this [repo](https://github.com/bizz84/stopwatch-flutter).

And then, if you want to press anywhere on the timer area and then the time starts and then do the same thing to start it, you can use the `GestureDetector` class ([here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)).

Comment: Ok so how would you do that in the repo